# ajax within each loop executing incorrectly

Tags: jquery, ajax, each

I have the following js snippet:

```
cat_images = $(".category-description").next().find("img");
cat_images.each(function () {
    url = $(this).parent().attr("href");
    id = url.split("id=");
    id = id[1];
    url = "cat_url.php?i="+id;
    this_image = this;

    $.get (url, function (data) {
        $(this_image).attr("src", data);
    });
 });
```

At the moment, only the last element iterated over by the each loop is being updated by the ajax.get section. I think it is something to do with the ajax interacting poorly with the loop as using `this` within the ajax function makes it fail entirely.

Regardless, is there anyway to delay the loop while waiting for the ajax to finish in Jquery? (would prefer not mixing regular js in)

Comment: It's because the `get` function is non-blocking (asynchronous), meaning the `each` loop continues on without waiting for a response.  By the time you get a response from any of the get calls you've finished iteration and `this_image` is equal to the last one.  See Vega's answer below for how to deal with this.

Answer (score 6):

Try wrapping it inside a closure,

```
cat_images.each(function () {
    url = $(this).parent().attr("href");
    id = url.split("id=");
    id = id[1];
    url = "cat_url.php?i="+id;
    this_image = this;

    (function (this_image) {
      $.get (url, function (data) {
        $(this_image).attr("src", data);
      });
    })(this_image);
 });
```

Comment: cheers! It's been an age since I even considered using a js closure - would never of occurred to me.

Comment: My initial thought was on using closures, then i thought i might be over-thinking :(. +1

Comment: An alternative would be to use $.ajax and pass this_image as the context

Answer (score 0):

Although it seems that Vega's solution works correctly, I'd advise you to change you logic a bit.

The problem is that, if you have 10 cat_images you're going to make 10 different requests, that's no very elegant.

You should consider creating a new cat_url.php that would receive one o more ids and would return all the URLs at once. Also you can id the images inside the html as cat_image so when you return the URLs as JSON you can set each src.

Your HTML snippet should be something like this:

```
<a href="url?id=1">
  <img src="..." id="cat_image1" rel="1" />
</a>
```

That would be yours final js snippet:

```
var ids = [];
cat_images.each(function () {
  ids.push($(this).attr("rel"));
});

var data = "ids=" + ids;
$.get ({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data) {
    for (var img in data.images) {
      $("#cat_image" + img.id).attr("src", img.url);
    };
  }
});
```

Your cat_images.php should return a JSON like this:

```
{
  images: [
    {id: 1, url: 'url1.jpg'},
    {id: 2, url: 'url2.jpg'},
    {id: 3, url: 'url3.jpg'}
  ]
}
```